# How to put app.config under app.config?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, app-config

I'm trying to create multiple app.config's for different build profiles, like app.debug.config and app.release.config. How do I put them under each other in Solution Explorer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The visual representation is based on the `DependentUpon` metadata in the csproj file.

For example when you have 3 config files, you can set the metadata as such:

```
<None Include="App.config" />
<None Include="App.Debug.config" DependentUpon="App.config" />
<None Include="App.Debug.BackupDb.config" DependentUpon="App.Debug.config" />
```

which results in the following representation in the solution explorer:

[image]

For older versions (pre-VS 2017) you will need to add the `DependentUpon` metadata as elements beneath the `None` element instead of adding it as attribute.

To be compatible with VS 2015 and lower, the xml for the item would be:

```
<None Include="App.Debug.config">
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
```

Comment: Is there no VS GUI for doing this?

Comment: none that I know of. some project systems have this logic built in - e.g. asp.net core projects for `appsettings.*.json` and I think even web projects may update the metadata when opening (not sure at the moment)

Comment: when added under `None` as an `element`, which `attribute` should be used for specifying the file name?

Comment: @mikael-dúi-bolinder When added under none as a sub element, do not use an attribute, just put `<DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>`

Answer (score 0):

By right-click on app. config and click on add config transforms.
if you can't find the add config transform you should download the configuration transform from manage Extentions in vs.